# Unstructured exception handling in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

My code in VB.NET keeps responding with build errors, but there are no mistakes detected by visual studio 2017.

The response I received was:

> There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?

And after that, I had received an error code saying:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Game, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>C:\Users\SAMSUNG\source\repos\Game\Game\Game.vb(48,29): error BC37234: Unstructured exception handling is not supported in current project type.
>   1>Done building project "Game.vbproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Here's my code

```
Imports System
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim Choice1 As Integer = 0
        Dim rng As New Random
        Dim strmod As Integer = 1
        Dim yourhit As Integer
        Dim revenge As Integer
        Dim Health As Integer = 5
        Console.WriteLine("Menu")
        Console.WriteLine("-----")
        Console.WriteLine("1.Training")
        Console.WriteLine("2.Battle")
        Choice1 = Console.ReadLine()
        For count = 1 To 10
            If Choice1 = 1 Then
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan
                Console.Clear()
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the training grounds!")
                Console.WriteLine("Press Key to hit!")
                Console.ReadKey()
                For counter = 1 To 10
                    yourhit = (rng.Next(1, 10) + strmod)
                    Console.WriteLine("You hit the dummy and deal {0} damage to it!", yourhit)
                    Console.ReadKey()
                Next
            ElseIf Choice1 = 2 Then
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan
                Console.Clear()
                yourhit = (rng.Next(1, 10) + strmod)
                revenge = (rng.Next(1, 10) + strmod)
                Console.WriteLine("A Soldier has ambushed you!")
                Console.WriteLine("Press Key to Fight Back!")
                For counter = 1 To 10
                    Console.ReadKey()
                    If yourhit > revenge Then
                        Console.WriteLine("You hit the soldier and do {0} damage to him!", yourhit)
                    ElseIf yourhit < revenge Then
                        Health = Health - revenge
                        If Health <= 0 Then
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
                            Console.Clear()
                            Console.WriteLine("YOU DIED!")
                            Console.ReadKey()
                            End
                        Else
                            Console.WriteLine("The soldier hit you and dealt {0} damage to you!", revenge)
                        End If
                    Else
                        Console.WriteLine("He blocked your attack!")
                    End If
                    Console.ReadKey()
                Next
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter 1 or 2 only...")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: "not supported in current project type". what is your current project type?

Comment: also try to "Clean" the build, exit VS and reopen project to see if error persists.

Comment: I think the code obscures the question. Does `Imports System` `Module Module1` `Sub Main()` `End Sub` `End Module` work? (present an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Jeremy, I'm using Console App (.NET Core)

Comment: This is a .NETCore specific problem, it is not happy about the `End` keyword.  As a workaround use `Return` instead.  Or more generally `Environment.Exit(0)`.  You can file the bug with Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: Thank you Hans! It worked  :D